# java split() method convert String to Integer

Tags: java, string, methods, split

I have got a string `"1,2,3"` and I need to split it and individual numbers convert to integer.

```
String s = "1,2,3";
String[] s2 = s.split(",");
for(String temp : s2 ) {
System.out.println(temp);
}
```

I know to split it but i don't know to convert it.
Sorry for my bad English. Thank you!

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(temp));

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Integer.parseInt(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) be aware abut the 
**NumberFormatException**

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "1,2,s,3";
    String[] s2 = s.split(",");
    int var = 0;
    for (String temp : s2) {
        try{
            var = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.err.println("Oops... that wasn't a number....");
        }finally{
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the for loop ? ( Lambda, stream, etc. ) ?